# p:tabMenu without form

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this `p:tabMenu`:

```
<p:tabMenu id="tabs" activeIndex="0" >  
    <p:menuitem value="General" url="/DCProfileTabGeneral.jsf"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Zones" url="/DCProfileTabZones.jsf"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="UPS" url="/DCProfileTabUPS.jsf"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Storages" url="/DCProfileTabStorages.xhtml"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Servers" url="/DCProfileTabServers.xhtml"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Racks" url="/DCProfileTabRacks.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Networks" url="/DCProfileTabNetworks.xhtml"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="ISPs" url="/DCProfileTabISPs.xhtml"/>                            
    <p:menuitem value="Generators" url="/DCProfileTabGenerators.xhtml" />  
    <p:menuitem value="HVACs" url="/DCProfileTabHVACs.xhtml"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="History" url="/DCProfileTabHistory.xhtml"/>

</p:tabMenu>
```

I noticed that on the Primefaces website [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabMenu.jsf) there is not a `h:form` in which the code must be placed. But when I test the code the get this message:

```
The form component needs to have a UIForm in it's ancestry.
```

It seems that I cannot run the code without a `h:form`. I want to run it without form. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: It's a warning message only and it is a mojarra issue I think. I change javax.faces.PROJECT_Stage as production then I won't get this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As anon stated, you can get rid of the message by changing your JSF context param to `PRODUCTION`. A word of caution: You **don't** get to submit anything to the server without wrapping it in a form. Any component that will or might end up generating a request to the server will give you this log message if you don't enclose it in a form. Ignore at your own peril.